# Escape a dot in mysql insert query

Tags: php, mysql

How do I escape a dot in insert query?

```
   insert into './$x/.' () lues( );
```

How to escape the dot before $x and after $x, I tried the above but did not work.

Comment: Does your table’s name really start and end with a dot?

Comment: @Gumbo:How do i concatenate a variable and a string.

Comment: A PHP variable’s value and what string? PHP string or MySQL string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back slash, not forward slash.

`\` 
also, you need to escape things by placing the escape character BEFORE the thing it's escaping.

E.g.

```
"INSERT INTO `\$my_table` VALUES(NULL,$asdf,$jkl)"
```

Ok, but in your case, try this:

```
insert into `.$x.` () lues( );
```

Those are not ' but `

That is the backtick character. Same key as ~ on U.S. keyboards.

Concatenating a variable and a string:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `' . $my_table . '` VALUES(NULL,asdf,' . $jkl . ')";
```

But inside of double quotes "" you can just put the variable names into the string:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `$my_table` VALUES(NULL,asdf,$jkl )";
```

(Both of the above result in the exact same string being assigned to variable $query)

Take a look at the PHP page on [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

You can see sections on single quote, double quote, and others that will blow your mind (HEREDOC).

Important: also check out 'parameterized queries'.

Comment: When i echo my query this is how i get insert into .1.x () values(),i want to get rid of dot before 1 and dot after one.I tried your solution ,it says warning unexpected input /

Comment: You might want to show us more of the surrounding code. What you posted doesn't even look like valid PHP or MySQL. Make it clear exactly what the name of your table IS, so that we can tell you how to send your query. Also, did you try surrounding the table name in ` and `?

Comment: "Use forward slash, not back slash." The character you're saying to use IS the back slash.

Comment: @Alkanshel I stand corrected! Fixed. And not a moment too soon!